# More than 6 providers for ProxyProvider, how?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Until now I used Singleton pattern in my code, but I'm switching to Remi Rousselet’s Provider. And I have a business logic class that depends on 7 others as for now. ProxyProvider allows to use up to 6. How do I implement Provider pattern in this case?

```
class BlocAuth {
  BlocAuth(this.serviceChatFirestore);
  ServiceChatFirestore serviceChatFirestore;
  var _state = AuthState();
  var blocUser = BlocUser();
  var user = UserModel();
  var blocRouting = BlocRouting();
  var blocBrands = BlocBrands();
  var blocNotifications = BlocNotifications();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ProxyProvider isn't actually fixed to any number of dependency.

ProxyProvider vs ProxyProvider6 is just some syntax sugar. The latter isn't actually needed

For example:

```dart
ProxyProvider3<A, B, C, Result>(
  builder: (_, a, b, c, previous) {
    ...
  }
)
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```dart
ProxyProvider<A, Result>(
  builder: (context, a, previous) {
    final b = Provider.of<B>(context);
    final c = Provider.of<C>(context);
    ...

  },
)
```

So you can just do:

```dart
ProxyProvider6<A, B, C, D, E, F, Result>(
  builder: (context, a, b, c, d, e, f previous) {
    final g = Provider.of<G>(context);
    ...
  }
)
```